# variant of functions with different return types

Tags: c++, variant, std-function

The code below does not compile:

```
#include <functional>
#include <variant>

int main() {
  using ret_void = std::function<void()>;
  using ret_int  = std::function<int()>;

  std::variant<ret_void, ret_int> var;
  var.emplace([](){ return 1; } );
}
```

The compile says `template argument deduction/substitution failed`. 
Can anyone explain why this fails to compile?

Comment: I think a lambda is not of type std::fuction, but a functor with a unique type under the hood

Comment: It's been my experience that type erasure (as is used by `std::function` to store different callable things) and template type deduction do not mix elegantly. You might be able to get away with explicitly constructing a `std::function` and using CTAD to still allow type deduction. Something like `var.emplace(std::function{[](){ return 1; }});` has worked for me and might work for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This fails to compile because [`std::variant::emplace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/emplace) needs to be given either the type or the index of the variant alternative to emplace:

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <variant>

int main() {
  using ret_void = std::function<void()>;
  using ret_int  = std::function<int()>;

  std::variant<ret_void, ret_int> var;
  var.emplace<ret_int>([](){ return 1; });
}
```

The first template parameter of all overloads of `std::variant::emplace` [[variant.mod]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/variant.mod) is either the index or the type of the variant alternative to emplace. None of these overloads use this parameter in a way that would make it deducible…